# $T_h$ is a bounded linear operator from $L^2[0,1]$ into $L^p[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Assume $C[0,1]$ has $p$-norm, $1 \leq p \leq \infty, \ h(x)\in C[0,1]$.

Define $T_h f(t) = h(t)f(t), \ t\in [0,1]$, find $p$ such that $T_h$ is a bounded linear operator from $L^2[0,1]$ into $L^p[0,1]$

My attempt:
Need to show $\Vert T_h f(t)\Vert_p \leq a\Vert f(t)\Vert_2$, for some $a\in [0,\infty)$.

Know by generalized $H\ddot{o}lder$’s Inequality,

$\Vert h(t)f(t)\Vert_p$ $\leq \Vert h(t)\Vert_r \Vert f(t)\Vert_2$, where $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{2}, 1\leq r\leq \infty$

Then for $\frac{2}{3}\leq p \leq 2$, it works. But I don't think this is a complete answer. And in this way, I cannot find the matrix norm.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot find a condition completely in terms of $p$. If $h=0$ then  any $p$ would be fine!. So you c an only expect a condition in terms of $p$ and the function $h$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthyThank you. Could you give some hint when $h \neq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer: If $p \leq 2$ then $\|hf\|_p \leq M\|f\|_p \leq M \|f\|_2 $, where $M=\|h\|_{\infty}$. So $T$ is  a bounded operator whenever $p \leq 2$. But this is not a necessary condition. $T$ can be bounded even when $p >2$. (Consider $h=0$).

If $\inf \{|h(x)|: 0 \leq x \leq 1\} >0$ then we can show that $p\leq 2$ is necessary and sufficient.

EDIT: As pointed out by MaoWao in his comment it is enough if $h $ is  not the zero function: there is an interval on which $|h| >0$ and, if $p>2$ we can find a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ on that interval such that $\{f_n\} \to 0$ in $L^{2}$ but not in $L^{p}$.

Comment: Thanks. Is $\Vert h \Vert_\infty$ the matrix norm here? I chose $f(t)=\mathbb{1}$, then$ \Vert hf \Vert_p =\Vert h \Vert_p$

Comment: @Flashhh $\|h\|_{\infty} =\sup \{|h(x)|: 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$.

Comment: Sorry. Should $\Vert f \Vert_2 \leq \Vert f \Vert_p$ when $p\leq2$

Comment: @Flashhh For any probability measure $\mu$ we have $\|f\|_p \leq \|f\|_q$ for $p \leq q$.

Comment: I think the necessary condition $p\leq 2$ is actually valid for any $h$ not identically zero, since you can always restrict to an interval where $|h|$ is strictly positive.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you for the observation. I have edited the answer and indicated how we can prove that $p \leq 2$ when $h$ is not the zero function.